# Find range of $\alpha$ of $ \frac{4x^2+1}{64x^2 - 96x \sin \alpha +5} \leq \frac{1}{32}$ for all real x.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I simplified it to get $ \frac{64x^2 + 96 x \sin \alpha +27}{64x^2 - 96 x \sin \alpha +5} \leq 0$. I dont have any idea how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

See get a quadratic . The equation is $64x^2+96x\sin(\alpha)+27\leq 0$ the value of quadratic is negative between it's roots so discriminant is greater than $0$ thus $9612sin^2(\alpha)\geq 6912$ thus $sin^2(\alpha)\geq 3/4$ so $\sin(\alpha)\geq \sqrt{3}/2$ thus range of alpha is $\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$

Comment: That's a good solution my friend !

Comment: @archis ,but how do you ensure the denominator  $64x^2 - 96 x \sin \alpha +5$ is positive

Comment: I directly used the given equation not the one you reduced to

Comment: The inequality is required to hold for all values of $x$. When $\sin^2\alpha \geq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, we can only say that there are values of $x$ for which the inequality holds.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Express it as a function and explore the function's regions (derivative, limits etc). This is what I'd do in such a case first thing of the bat. If something can be defined that way, then you should explore other ways (depending on what you study, since every mathematical question usually has a lot of solutions).